# Why does my phone not show the saved file created in my app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTYR3FBDus4) tutorial line for line in a separate project to my main one just to make sure it is working correctly prior to adding it into my main code. When I run it on my Samsung galaxy S8, the text file with the data saved is nowhere to be seen in storage!

My code compiles and runs on the phone. Using the code:

```
package com.example.joshgascoigne.storagedummy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ed1;
    Button btn1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ed1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        btn1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void save(View v){
        String FILENAME = "StoredData";
        String Data = ed1.getText().toString();

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        try {
            fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fos.write(Data.getBytes());
            Toast.makeText(this, "Data Saved: " + getFilesDir() + "/" + FILENAME, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

With the Toast it shows that the text is saved and shows me the directory it should be saved to, however, the directory does not exist, nor does it exist in any sort of file similar to what is shown in the tutorial. What am I doing wrong and why can I not access the text file?

EDIT: I have now tried running the code on am emulator, i get an exception possibly from my try catch, involving the saving of data reading:

**java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\Josh%20Gascoigne.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is read-only.**

I believe this to be the error but unsure how best to fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You use openFileOutput() which saves files in getFilesDir().

That is an app private storage location and cannot be accessed by other apps.

Hence file explorers and file managers cannot find them.

Comment: I see, how does this work within the tutorial then?

Comment: Dont know. I will not look at that video to begin with.

Comment: Oh, why not may I ask? i have looked into a lot of solutions and tutorials, all showing fileOutputStream as a method of storing data which can be accessed in the android device file explorer so i am extremely confused as to why my versions are not working

Comment: also, i added an edit, using an emulator, which threw back an error which i wasn't getting when using the phone. Is this in relation to your original answer, basically saying my directory is read only and cannot be accessed externally? or is this another issue

Comment: I hate looking videos for code. Simple. And C: is a Windows partition and i have no idea why you have that IOException. Try another emulator.